# Autofac multiple resolved twice components with ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

Disclaimer: This is my first use of Autofac (I am familiar with DI,but used other container registries), so I am still reading about how to set up Autofac while following the best practices.

I was just throw into the project and asked to find the memory leak as well. I have narrowed it down to our usage of Autofac, but I am struggling to figure out how it is being used incorrectly. I did run Autofac.Analysis and here are the messages I am seeing. I am reading a lot, but not finding a solution for these.

**Setup:**

All of the builder registrations are done in the Startup.cs

Registrations snippet (they look ok to me, but I am no Autofac expert)

```
            builder.RegisterType<HttpContextFactory>().As<IHttpContextFactory>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>().As<IHttpContextAccessor>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<ActionContextAccessor>().As<IActionContextAccessor>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<OpenIdAuthEvents>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<IntegrationIdentityProvider>().As<IPrincipalContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired();
            builder.RegisterType<IntegrationIdentityProvider>().As<IIntegrationIdentityProvider>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired();
```

```
A003 The non-shared component 70b960dd277a470e844c84cfbdd6b2ec, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.DefaultCorsPolicyProvider, has been resolved twice directly from the container. This usage pattern can lead to memory leaks when tracked/`IDisposable` components are present. 

Level (Warning)

Type (0x37AE056A)

AnalysisCode 
A003

AutofacAnalysisSessionId 
78c114c7fe244e77a1686db4c162986c

ComponentDescription 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.DefaultCorsPolicyProvider

ComponentId 
70b960dd277a470e844c84cfbdd6b2ec

SourceContext 
Autofac.Analysis.Display.EventWriter
```

This same exact message also happens for the following components as well.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider
Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceScopeFactory
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IStartupFilter[]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Builder.ApplicationBuilderFactory
```

I am not sure if this is helpful, but it may give some insight into how this is set up. I see the following when making an HTTP request.

```
A002 A <level 1> lifetime scope, 2474db230bfe44f9b4a2a22f71a8053a, has been active for more than 10 seconds. To ensure that components are properly released, lifetime scopes must be disposed when no longer required. 

AgeThresholdSeconds 
10

AnalysisCode 
A002

AutofacAnalysisSessionId 
f4d97c3ec5144ad8bfe23d0afe8d5755

LifetimeScopeDescription 
<level 1>

LifetimeScopeId 
2474db230bfe44f9b4a2a22f71a8053a

SourceContext 
Autofac.Analysis.Display.EventWriter
```

Comment: Why do you think that your problem is related to Autofac?

Comment: It may not be, but I was told by the owner of the project to start there. I am also seeing this in the analysis, but it may not be Autofac. 

Here is what I am seeing in the logs

https://share.getcloudapp.com/rRuqdO2K